# cloning an index of an array of objects in javascript (client-side ReactJS) and return a view based on the new array using map method

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a ReactJS application, in one component I have a table and I create each table row using map() method in component view (JSX) where every single row has a duplicate button so the user can duplicate a row and see it under the item they clicked on. for example: if the user clicks on the second row duplicate button, I want to clone the index 1 of page data array and update the component view based on the new array.

here's the simplified code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
const [PageData, setPageData] = useState([
  {name: "item1", id: "1"},
  {name: "item2", id: "2"},
  {name: "item3", id: "3"}
])
 const duplicateItem = (RowItem, i) => {
  let RowsData = [...PageData];
  let Index = parseInt(i + 1);
  RowsData.splice(Index, 0, Duplicate);
  setPageData(RowsData);
 }

return (
  <div>
   {PageData.map((Item, i) =>(
      <div className="form-row" key={i}>
       <p>{Item.name}</p>
        <button
           onClick={() => duplicateItem(Item, i)}
           className="duplicate"
        >
        </button>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
 )
}
export default MyComponent;
```

what we expect to happen is that when the user clicks on the duplicate button, a row is added under the item the user clicked on (if they duplicate the second item, a duplicate of it will appear under the second item), I don't know why this code is not working and today is my deadline so I need help.

Comment: If you put a break point in duplicateItem is it called? What happens when you step through it?

Comment: yes it is called, why though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like shown below.

For simplicity, I have used the array length for updating the `id` of the newly added duplicated item. Also, in `duplicateItem` you are already receiving the item to be duplicated, so we can use the same for adding below the selected item.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const MyComponent = () => {
const [PageData, setPageData] = useState([
  {name: "item1", id: "1"},
  {name: "item2", id: "2"},
  {name: "item3", id: "3"}
])
 const duplicateItem = (RowItem, i) => {
  setPageData(data => {
      let RowsData = [...data];
    //Create a new ID, for simplicity I'm just using the length of the array
    const id = `${RowsData.length + 1}`;
    //Add the same item with new id below the selected item
    const Index = parseInt(i + 1);
    RowsData.splice(Index, 0, {...RowItem, id});
    return RowsData;
  });
 }

return (
  <div>
   {PageData.map((Item, i) =>(
      <div className="form-row" key={i}>
       <p>{Item.name}_{Item.id}</p>
        <button
           onClick={() => duplicateItem(Item, i)}
           className="duplicate"
        >
        </button>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
 )
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the great response, this method works perfectly. What if I have a few other properties I want to add besides id? like a status (boolean) or a select element that the user can change and duplicate with the new values? Can it be done with the same approach?

Comment: Yes, you can add as many properties as you want. Like how we added new `id`, if you wish to have a default value for `status` like `false` you can add it or you can provide an option to the user to select `status` and use the same.

Comment: But, before duplication if you change the value, then that value will be updated for the original value as well. One way is to copy the same object and provide an option to change the value after the duplicated item gets added to the list.

Comment: Noted, I keep getting the wrong row and the duplicated item is added to the end of the list and not to the index I want.

Comment: Is it so, but when I checked it's working as expected. In order to avoid such confusion, I have updated the answer by adding the `id` to the list item name in the render while displaying. Please check once.

Comment: yes, I had another bug in my UI that caused the problem. Your solution works perfectly, thanks!